# SOA record in AAAA query reply when IPv6 is not supported

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6

When I do dig AAAA to a website that doesn't support IPv6 yet, the reply has an SOA record.

Is it a requirement to have the SOA record in response to a AAAA query when the service doesn't support IPv6 ?

```
    dig quora.com AAAA

    ; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.6-Ubuntu <<>> quora.com AAAA
    ;; global options: +cmd
    ;; Got answer:
    ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 8704
    ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

    ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
    ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
    ;; QUESTION SECTION:
    ;quora.com.         IN  AAAA

    ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
    quora.com.      976 IN  SOA ns1.p28.dynect.net. zone-admin.dyndns.com. 2016031101 3600 600 604800 3600

    ;; Query time: 35 msec
    ;; SERVER: 10.0.2.3#53(10.0.2.3)
    ;; WHEN: Mon Mar 21 08:27:49 UTC 2016
    ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 110
```

Comment: The `SOA` is isn't an Answer - its simply telling you who is authoritative for the domain. The lack of an Answer or Error for `AAAA` indicates the absence of that record

Comment: I understand that SOA isn't an Answer. But my question is, is it required to include the SOA record in this case ? dig AAAA for a service that does have IPv6 support doesn't have the SOA record in the reply.

Comment: Ok, I had just wanted to clarify^^. I'll save the '_required_' part for whomever pulls an answer from the RFC; but note you will find the same behavior if you dig for an absent `A`, or any other rr in a valid zone

Comment: Thanks @pete you nerd snipped me into going and finding the RFC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that this occurs is for Negative Response Caching. i.e. if you do a AAAA query for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and that record doesn't exist then the fact that it doesn't exist will be added to the cache of the intermediate servers.

In order for those intermediate servers to know how long to cache that response for, they need the SOA record; because that is where TTL is defined. This process is completely protocol agnostic, IPv4 and IPv6 (as well as [IPv9](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1606)) get the same response included in the `additional` field.

#### Edited in response to comment

(it seems my previous edit was rather incorrect! - So here's the real one)

As a result the SOA record is inserted into the Authority section.

According to RFC 2308 [Negative Caching of DNS Queries](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2308#section-3) Section 3

> Name servers authoritative for a zone MUST include the SOA record of
> the zone in the authority section of the response when reporting an
> NXDOMAIN or indicating that no data of the requested type exists.
> This is required so that the response may be cached.

#### Edited for anyone curious after reading the comments here!

It seems that the original DNS RFC 1034 [Domain Concepts and Facilities](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034) had an issue in describing two locations for the SOA, the authority section (in section 3.7) and the additional section (which I'd originally quoted, in section 4.3.4) RFC 2181 section 7.1 [Clarifications to the DNS Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181#section-7.1) clarified this. [RFC 2308](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2308) later replaced section 4.3.4 entirely.

> Abstract
>
> [RFC1034] provided a description of how to cache negative
> responses.    It however had a fundamental flaw in that it did not
> allow a name    server to hand out those cached responses to other
> resolvers, thereby    greatly reducing the effect of the caching.
> This document addresses    issues raise in the light of experience and
> replaces [RFC1034 Section
> 4.3.4].

Comment: Your IPv9 link is a joke. IANA has [allocated](http://www.iana.org/assignments/version-numbers/version-numbers.xhtml#version-numbers-1) version number 9 to [RFC 1347](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1347) (which nobody is using).

Comment: @kasperd Are you sure? I've just got my 1 billion IPV9 addresses assigned for my house (and due to some bureaucratic fumbling, 2 billion assigned to my shed - not to mention the million the dog had allocated, though that could just be based on flee count) - Although, DNS is still protocol agnostic, whether we're talking IPV4,6 or 9 (whether the april fool's version or tuba - which does use DNS) You'll still get an SOA with the reply.(if only I was smart enough to have made that the joke)

Comment: To explain the joke (and therefore ruthlessly murder it): whether the version of IP is real or imaginary, DNS as a protocol is agnostic to the transport layer. It has no idea what version of IP the requesting client implements, nor does it care. You get exactly what you ask for, V4 or otherwise, and it's up to the OS's stub resolver to be smart enough to ask for what it needs.

Comment: @MichaelB The section you quoted from the RFC seems to be indicate that the SOA record should be in the Additional section. But in the dig reply I see its in the Authority section. Not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Manohar [RFC 2308 §2.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2308#section-2.2) is a better link. Your example reply is a synthetic state called NODATA, where the server is saying that the requested name exists but not with that particular record type. Note that the first paragraph states *"The authority section will contain an SOA record, or there will be no NS records there."*.

Comment: @Manohar I have modified the answer to address your comment.

Comment: @Michael Please review your edit. Your RFC citation is the integer counters of the various sections (irrelevant in this context), and the last paragraph is incorrect. SOA would be in authority section, and neither section is restricted to name servers.

Comment: @AndrewB I have edited the answer a little, with a better quote from 1035. The authority section is only for Nameservers that are authoritative for the domain. I have seen no other part of the RFC that states that anything other than Nameservers can be present in the Authority section.

Comment: That's because you can't use the RFCs comprising [STD 13](https://tools.ietf.org/html/std13) as an exhaustive reference for the specification. They've been updated by numerous RFCs. Suffice it to say: 1) the reply that you see in the question contains a SOA record in the authority section, and 2) the RFC 2308 citation I included above directly contradicts this assertion. The authority field *frequently* contains the SOA data when the rcode is `NXDOMAIN` or when the response is the synthetic state `NODATA`. (rcode `NOERROR` + 0 answers)

Comment: @AndrewB I appreciate the correction, thank you. (Although I'm now likely to need to go and figure out where that changed - so thanks! for that too)

Comment: That's the correct citation, you just had the wrong RFC name. Fixed it for you, looks good now.